# finite union of connected dense subsets of $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

For each $i\in\{1,2,\dots ,n\}$ define a set $$A_i:= \bigg\{(x,y)\colon x\in(k_i,k_i+1) , y\neq 0\bigg\}$$, to be dense and connected in $(k_i,k_i+1)\times\Bbb R$ where the $k_i$ are integer numbers . Put$$ M:=\bigg\{(x,0)\colon x\in\Bbb R\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}(k_i,k_i+1)\bigg\}.$$ Now, $$D:= \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_i \cup M$$ I am sure that $D$ is still a connected subset of $\Bbb R^2$ since the density of $A_i$ will ensure that they will have a limit point in common, By using the well known fact that says :If $B\subset\Bbb R^2$ is connected and $x$ is a limit of of $B$, then $B\cup \{x\}$ is still connected.

My question I need to see if my explanation is strong enough to show that $D$ is connected subset $\Bbb R^2$,  Thank you in advance.

**Edit**: The original was missing an important assumption for $A_i$ which is $y\neq 0$

Comment: The $A_i$ are *not* connected because of the $y \neq 0$ requirement. They *are* dense and open in $(k_i, k_i+1) \times \Bbb R$.

Comment: Henno Brandsma, $A_i$ is connected by the assumption. Why you said it is not connected?

Comment: you give the definition and that set is not connected

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, I think I see why said it is disconnected maybe you considered all $y$ expect $0$ which is not the case since i do mention that $A_i$ is connected. Anyway, I am very sure the $D$ would be connected but I was looking for different explanations rather than what I said. see also, Rob Arthan's answer

Comment: You **define** $A_i = \{(k_i, k_i+1) \times \{y \in \Bbb R\mid y \neq 0\}$ and this set is disconnected, so you cannot "assume" it is connected. Adding $M$ makes the union still not connected.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, As I mentioned I did not take all $y$ . of course this would not be connected. but it follows from context since I defined $A_i$ and I said it is connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) this is the answer before you added the condition that $y \neq 0$ to the definition of the $A_i$:**

Your statements about density and limit points aren't really the important things here. To see that $D$ is connected, show that it contains the $x$-axis, $X$ say, which meets each of the connected sets $A_i$. As the $x$-axis is connected this means that $D$ is connected, because you can write $D$ as:
$$
D = \bigcup_{i=1}^n (A_i \cup X)
$$
which displays $D$ as the union of a family of connected sets $X_i = A_i \cup M$ such that the intersections $X_i \cap X_j$ are all non-empty.

**2) now you have added the condition that $y \neq 0$ to the definition of the $A_i$, the set $D$ remains connected:**

To see this, let $D'$ be $D$ as it was without the restriction that $y\neq 0$ in the definition of the $A_i$. Then

$$
D = D' \setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^n (k_i, k_i + 1)\times \{0\}
$$

Removing these open line segments from $D'$ does not disconnect it, in the same way that removing a rung from a ladder (with at least two rungs) does not disconnect it).

To give a more formal proof, observe that you can replace each $A_i$ in the definition by:
$$
B_i:= \left\{(x,y)\colon x\in(k_i,k_i+1) , y\neq 0 \mbox{ or } x \in \{k_i, k_i+1\}\right\}
$$
since the points I have added to $A_i$ to form $B_i$ are in $M$. It is easy to see that the $B_i$ are path-connected (or you can use your argument about limit points to display $B_i$ as the union of two intersecting connected sets). The closed line segments in the set $M$ then join each $B_i$ to its east and west neighbours. To be even more formal, you can show by induction that $D$ can be constructed by repeatedly taking the union of pairs of intersecting connected sets.

Comment: Rob Arthan, I think there is somethng wrong how $A_i$ will meet $x$-axis since the pair $(x,0)\notin A_i$

Comment: I see you have accepted the answer: does it make sense now?

Comment: Rob Arthan, I thought,it is correct but I do not think they will meet

Comment: $(x, 0) \in A_i$ for every $x \in (k_i, k_i + 1)$. It might help you to draw a diagram.

Comment: Rob Arthan, it is not for all $y$

Comment: You haven'r constrained $y$ in the definition of $A_i$ so it can take on any value.

Comment: Rob Arthan, I fixed.

Comment: Well, many thanks for missing out a vital part of your question! $\ddot{\frown}$.

Comment: Rob Arthan, No this would not be the case,n one $n=1$, $D$ will consider as union of connected  three pieces that have a limit point in common, $M=(-\infty, 0]\times \{0\}\cup [0,\infty)\times \{0\}.$ density $A_i$ is very important

Comment: Two (or more) connected sets can have a common limit point, while their union is not connected: e.g., $(-\infty, 0)$ and $(0, \infty)$ in $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Rob Arthan , notice that $(0,0)$ is limit of $(-\infty,0]\times \{0\}$ since it closed and is limit point for $A_i$ by density, In you last comment none of two intervals contain $0$

Comment: I think you are probably right, but "density" hasn't much to do with it. I'll try to fix the second part of my answer tomorrow.

Comment: Rob it was a useful discussion . I am very sure $D$ will be connected but I want to see an smart way to check that.

Comment: Rob Arthan, if you do not mind just delete the second part of your answer since people might think it is correct. Thank you so much

Comment: I've added a disclaimer.

Comment: Rob Arthan , I see thank you

Comment: I have fixed part 2 of the answer.

Comment: Rob Arthan, Thank you so much.